# What is the difference between having an auto type and having dynamic typing?

Tags: variables, data-types

In C++, you can define variables with `auto` instead of giving it a default type such as `int`. Like this (where `foo` is an int):

```
int x = foo
auto y = foo
```

Both contain `foo`.

In Python, you can define a variable without specifying the data type. Like this:

```
x = foo
```

The compiler determines the type of the variable at runtime based on the type of data assigned.

What are the differences between using an `auto` datatype and dynamic typing?

Comment: For one, and I think it's the most mentioned disadvantage for C++, figuring out what the type of the variable actually is can get pretty hard if your IDE isn't top notch. Especially if `foo` is a templated function that can depend on its' parameter values.

Comment: This question may be naively posed, but answers need not be. This may already have answers elsewhere in Internet. I am most interested in differences from the programmer's (ie user of the language) point of view, especially the implications for how code is structured/organised.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`auto` is an **inferred** type but it's still a **static** type. The difference is that the compiler knows what every value's type is in a statically-typed language (including the actual type of the `auto` values), but in a dynamically-typed language the type is only known at runtime. Also, variables in a statically-typed language have one fixed type even if they're declared with `auto`, but variables in a dynamic language can change types during program execution.

---

Consider the following C++ code:

```cpp
int main() {
  auto foo = "hello";
  puts(foo / 5);
}
```

This code will fail to **compile**, because you can't divide a `const char*` by an integer. Notably, even though `foo` is declared with type `auto`, the compiler knows that it's actual type is `const char*`. In fact, using `const char* foo = "hello"` gives the exact same semantics, `auto` is just syntax sugar for the programmer.

Now, consider the corresponding Python code:

```python
def main():
  foo = "hello"
  print(foo / 5)
```

This code will fail at **runtime** if/when `main` is called. Python doesn't statically check types, so while you also can't divide a string by an integer, it's only detected when `foo / 5` actually runs.

---

Failing at compile-time is generally regarded as better, but there are other drawbacks to static types (see: ["What are the pros and cons of static typing?"](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/587/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-static-typing/655#655)). For example, you can't assign an `auto` variable a value of a different type than it was declared with, because it still has a single consistent ("static") type, the type is just inferred.

```cpp
int main() {
  // This is OK, `foo` has type `const char*`
  auto foo = "hello";
  foo = "world";
  // So is this, `bar` has type `int`
  auto bar = 42;
  bar = 45;
  // However, this doesn't compile, because `foo` has already been assigned type `const char*`
  foo = 48;
}
```

But you can assign differently-typed values the same variable in a language with dynamic types, because `foo` has no consistent type (it's type is "dynamic").

```python
# This code runs as expected, with no errors
foo = "hello"
print(foo)
foo = 42
print(foo / 2)
```